# Hide systems buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, air

In my phone buttons located on the display. I cretae app and tested on phone. Apart from my app I see three dots. How to hide it?

Please help!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

AIR can not hide these three dots which are back, home and task buttons that we call the on-screen navigation bar.

To do that, you can use an [**AIR Native Extension ( ANE )**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) like the [AndroidFullScreen ANE](https://github.com/mesmotronic/air-fullscreen-ane/releases).

Download the `AndroidFullScreen.ane` file from the same link and then add it to your AIR for Android Flash project from : **File** -> **ActionScript Settings...** -> **Library Path** tab and select it :

[image: Add ANE file to an AIR for Android Flash project]

Then you can use one of examples that you can download from the same page to verify if your device can hide the Android on-screen navigation bar or not, because not all mobile devices support that ( I tested 2 mobile devices and none of them has been able to do that ).

Hope that can help.