# Can not run ANE

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

My development enviroment - Adobe Flash Professioan CC.

Create app for Android.

Target - AIR 3.8 for Android

[I downloaded .ane](https://github.com/mesmotronic/air-fullscreen-ane/releases) and added it to my project.

All my code:

```
import com.mesmotronic.ane.AndroidFullScreen;
import flash.events.*;

fullScreenButton.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, fullScreenButton_touchHandler);
function fullScreenButton_touchHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    AndroidFullScreen.hideSystemUI();
}
```

After run app appear window with text: `Failed test video at startup`

And error message:

> C:\Users\1BF82~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Tmp_ANE_File_Unzipped_Packages\AndroidFullScreen.ane

Comment: Provide more information buddy, it's very unclear what you're asking, where you get this error from, etc..

Comment: As I told you in [my answer for your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148192/hide-systems-buttons/28153741#28153741), you have to add the `.ane` to your project.

Comment: I added but have error

Comment: Save your project and put the `.ane` file into the same dir as it and then add the `.ane` to your project and compile.

Comment: I need set any permissions to app.xml?